# Link coreldraw characteristics

Tags: corel-draw, paragraph, copy-and-paste, content

Is there any option to "link" paragraph content and characteristics something similar to object style

posted an example where i have to copy some contents from left to the empty right side
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could use Edit > Clone if you just want to duplicate the text from one side to the other.

Or if you want to import data from a text cvs text file use the File > Print Merge comand.